# How to initialize size of array of object pointe to Dynamic Size?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an array of object pointer, NOT an object array.

However, I don't know how to initialize the size of the array.

So I tried `Object * obj[number]`, and number which has input by a user with `std::cin >> number` it doesn't work.

But the following code is creating object array.

```cpp
Object * object = new Object[number];
```

How can I initialize the size of `array of object pointer` to dynamic size?

Here is my code.

```cpp
class Object
{
...
    Team* team;
    size_t number{};
...
public:
...
    Object(size_t number);
...
};

Object::Object(size_t number): number(number), team(nullptr)
{
    if (number > 0) {

        Team* team[number]; // doesn't work..


    }
    else {
        team = nullptr;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int mCount;

    std::cout << "Input number of people : ";
    std::cin >> mCount;

    Object team1(mCount);
    std::cout << team1.getTeamInfo() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Object ** object = new Object*[number];` - though it's preferable to use a container, such as `std::vector` (also why do you need an array of pointers?)

Comment: Just use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>>`.

Comment: @UnholySheep But it means, team[][]. I don't want it.. and I have to use an array of pointers..

Comment: @bitmask Thanks for advice, but I have to use an array.

Comment: Is it an assignment or why do you have to use an array?

Comment: @bitmask kinds of assignment..? But not an assignment.. it's complicated..

Comment: You cannot have an array of pointers with dynamic size in a different way in standard C++. If you don't want it you cannot do the task as you described it

Comment: In that case, what UnholySheep said. C++ does not support VLAs.

Comment: @UnholySheep @bitmask Thanks.. then I may need to use `std::vector`. :)